# Stripping Commas and Periods

Tags: python, file-io, stripping

I am currently trying to input a text file, separate each word and organize them into a list.

The current problem I'm having is getting rid of commas and periods from the text file.

My code is below:

```
#Process a '*.txt' file.
def Process():
    name = input("What is the name of the file you would like to read from? ")

    file = open( name , "r" )
    text = [word for line in file for word in line.lower().split()]
    word = word.replace(",", "")
    word = word.replace(".", "")

    print(text)
```

The output I'm currently getting is this:

```
['this', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'line', 'of', 'the', 'file.', 'this', 'is', 'the', 'second', 'line.']
```

As you can see, the words "file" and "line" have a period at the end of them.

The text file I'm reading is:

> This is the first line of the file.
>
> This is the second line.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

These lines have no effect

```
word = word.replace(",", "")
word = word.replace(".", "")
```

just change your list comp to this:

```
[word.replace(",", "").replace(".", "") 
 for line in file for word in line.lower().split()]
```

Comment: Did they use to have an effect? For some reason my teacher told us to look at them?

Comment: They don't have an effect in this case because after the list comprehension is done, `word` will always be a reference to the last word in your list of words. @jamylak's version of the code correctly does the replacements on each word in the list as it's being handled.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe `strip` is more appropriate than `replace`

```
def Process():
    name = input("What is the name of the file you would like to read from? ")

    file = open(name , "r")
    text = [word.strip(",.") for line in file for word in line.lower().split()]
    print(text)
```

```
>>> help(str.strip)
Help on method_descriptor:

strip(...)
    S.strip([chars]) -> string or unicode

    Return a copy of the string S with leading and trailing
    whitespace removed.
    If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.
    If chars is unicode, S will be converted to unicode before stripping
```

Comment: Huh, cool. Thanks so much! I'll try this now.
...Annd it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 chars = [',', '.']

 word.translate(None, ''.join(chars))
```

For Python3

```
 chars = [',', '.']
 word.translate({ord(k): None for k in chars})
```